# Deleting Records in Sql while dsiplayed in table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-delete

I have a problem on Deleting my records it delete records but it always delete the first record not the corresponding data that I choose.

```
function deleterec()
{
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "inventory";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $getstarteds = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM record");
    $getstarteds->execute();
    $displayrecs = $getstarteds->fetch();
    if (count($displayrecs) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $displayrecs['id'];
        $checkrec = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO archive SELECT * from record where id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
        if ($checkrec->execute()) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM record WHERE id='" . $displayrecs['id'] . "'";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Record is Deleted")';
                echo '</script>';
                echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='main.php'\",100);</script>";
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EydAz.png)

here is my view code

```
$getstarteds = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM record");
$getstarteds->execute();
$displayrecs = $getstarteds->fetchAll();
echo"<table class='table table responsive' id='example'>";

foreach($displayrecs as $displayrec)
 {
  echo"<tr>";
  echo"<td>".$displayrec['eq_type']."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$displayrec['eq_num']."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$displayrec['model']."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$displayrec['serial_num']."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$displayrec['location']."</td>";
  echo"<td>".date("F j, Y",strtotime($displayrec['date_added']))."</td>";
  echo"<td><form action='main.php' method='POST'><button name='deletethis' class='btn btn-costume1'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></button><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myEdit' class='btn btn-costume3'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></form></td>";
  echo"</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: Oh god, please paginate your code properly. That is impossible to read. @bansi thank you :)

Comment: Thank You @bansi 
newbie here sorry

Comment: Share view code also ?

Comment: @Niklesh here's the view code

Comment: You are not posting deleting record id

Answer (score 0):

Your select `$getstarteds = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM record");` without `WHERE` condition and this line `$displayrecs = $getstarteds->fetch();` always get the first record

Comment: I think that's also the problem. how should I select it and be delete properly?

Comment: It depends on you, how u get the id of record you want to delete.
For example: If you POST your id your code will be like that: 
`$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM record WHERE id = ".$_POST['id']);`